# What is the significance of the gematria of יצחק, יעקב, יוסף all being multiples of the gematria of הוי״ה?

Tags: gematria-numerology

The gematria of יצחק is 208, which is 8 x 26.

The gematria of יעקב is 182, which is 7 x 26.

The gematria of יוסף is 156, which is 6 x 26.

Is there are significance to the relationship of all of them being multiples of הוי״ה?

Comment: You forgot פינחס=208, ארז=208, and many more. Try it yourself at https://www.gimatria.co.il/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Panim Yafos ([Vayishlach](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39320&st=&pgnum=42&hilite=)), when Yitzchok (208; 8x26) gave the *berachos* to Yackov, he transmitted 7 levels of *kedusha* (symbolized by 26, which is the numerical value of הוי"ה) to Yackov (182; 7x26).

When Esav came in and demanded a blessing of his own, he said:

> ויאמר עשו אל אביו **הברכה אחת הוא לך** אבי ברכני גם אני אבי

Yitzchok is 208, which is 8x26. After transmitting 7 levels of *kedusha* to Yackov, he was left with one - the *berachah achas* that Esav demanded. Yitzchok indeed blessed Esav with the remaining one.

Esav (עשו) is 376, which corresponds to 7 levels of impurity (טמא=50) and one level of holiness. (376=(7x50)+26)

When Yackov and Esav met each other, Yackov countered Esav murderous intentions by bowing seven times:

> והוא עבר לפניהם וישתחו ארצה שבע פעמים עד גשתו עד אחיו

Panim Yafos explains that Yackov bowed 7 times; each bow signified a conflict between one of Yackov's 7 levels of *kedusha* against one of Esav's seven levels of *tumah* (See Maharsha to Kiddushin 29 explaining the 'story' of R' Acha bar Yackov bowing seven times, thus defeating a seven headed serpent).

---

*Disclaimer: I do not profess to understand the depths of the concepts I quote; they deserve to be treated with reverence nonetheless.*

Answer (score 0):

The Panim Yafos does not really address Yosef though in the OP. I found an answer from the Bar-Ilan University Parsha on Vayechi.

בית הספר ללימודי יסוד ביהדות                                                        פרשת ויחי, תשע"ו
ע"ש הלנה ופאול שולמן                                                                        מספר 1150

המשמעות הסמלית של קורות יעקב ויוסף
רפאל שוח"ט

עורך: פרופ' עמוס פריש

עורכת לשון: רחל הכהן שיף

> **ד ף  ש ב ו ע י**
>
> פרשת זו נקראת פרשת "ויחי" אף שתחילתה פטירתו של יעקב וסופה פטירתו של
> יוסף. ר' יצחק כהנא (נפטר תר"ס) כתב שיש מסורת מהגר"א שבכל פרשה יש כלל
> ופרט וכלל.<sup>[1](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1713761/jewish/Abaye-amp-Souls-of-Converts-345a.htm)</sup> כאן הכלל הראשון הוא פטירת יעקב ואילו הכלל
> האחרון הוא פטירת יוסף. מהו הקשר המיוחד ביניהם? כתוב: "אֵלֶּה תֹּלְדוֹת
> יַעֲקֹב יוֹסֵף" (בר' לז:ב), וכתוב זה רומז לכך שעיקר תולדות יעקב הוא
> יוסף. וכן כתוב: וַיְהִי כַּאֲשֶׁר יָלְדָה רָחֵל אֶת־יוֹסֵף וַיֹּאמֶר
> יַעֲקֹב אֶל־לָבָן שַׁלְּחֵנִי וְאֵלְכָה" (בר' ל:כה). על פסוק זה כתב
> רש"י: "משנולד שטנו של עשו" ביקש יעקב ללכת. יוסף הוא שטנו של עשו,
> ככתוב: "וְהָיָה בֵית־יַעֲקֹב אֵשׁ וּבֵית יוֹסֵף לֶהָבָה וּבֵית עֵשָׂו לְקַשׁ
> וְדָלְקוּ בָהֶם וַאֲכָלוּם" (עוב' א:יח). בית יעקב הוא האש ואילו בית יוסף
> הוא הלהבה וההמשכיות של מאבקו של יעקב בעשו. מה פשר עניין זה?
>
> שלוש פרשיות מאפיינות את חייו של יעקב. על דברי רבקה "עָלַי קִלְלָתְךָ
> בְּנִי" (בר' כז:יג) אמר הגר"א: "'עלי' ראשי תבות עשו, לבן,
> יוסף".<sup>[2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_HaTor.2?ven=Kol_HaTor&lang=en)</sup> המאבק עם לבן היה קשה, ככתוב: "אֲרַמִּי אֹבֵד
> אָבִי" (דב' כו:ה), ואמרו חז"ל: "מלמד שביקש לבן לעקור את
> הכל".<sup>[3]</sup> אלא שהיו אלו ייסורים זמניים של קיפוח פרנסתו (בר'
> לא:ז, וכן לא:מא), החלפת אשתו, (בר' כט:כה) ורצונו לפגוע ביעקב (בר'
> לא:ז, כט).  כשהגיעו להר הגלעד הצליח יעקב להתגבר על לבן ולסיים פרשה זו.
>
> בניגוד למאבק עם לבן, המאבק עם עשו הוא תמידי. חז"ל אמרו: "הלכה היא
> בידוע שעשו שונא ליעקב" (ראו רש"י בר' לג:ד). ואכן, כשעשו מציע ללוותו
> (בר' לב:יב) יעקב עונה לו: "יַעֲבָר־נָא אֲדֹנִי לִפְנֵי עַבְדּוֹ... עַד
> אֲשֶׁר־אָבֹא אֶל־אֲדֹנִי שֵׂעִירָה" (בר' לג:יד). והרי הלך לדרכו, "אלא
> אימתי הוא בא אצלו, לעתיד לבוא הדא הוא דכתיב 'וְעָלוּ מוֹשִׁעִים בְּהַר
> צִיּוֹן לִשְׁפֹּט אֶת־הַר עֵשָׂו' (עוב' א:כא)".<sup>[4]</sup> המאבק עם עשו
> דומה למאבק עם שׂרו של עשו, עם שורשו. "וַיֵּאָבֵק אִישׁ עִמּוֹ עַד עֲלוֹת
> הַשָּׁחַר" (בר' לב: כד), כלומר לכל אורך הגלות שנמשלה ללילה. איש זה,
> שבמקום אחר נאמר עליו שהיה מלאך: "וַיָּשַׂר אֶל־מַלְאָךְ" (הושע יב:ה),
> הוא גם סמל המאבק הזה: "הֲלוֹא־אָח עֵשָׂו לְיַעֲקֹב נְאֻם ה' וָאֹהַב
> אֶת־יַעֲקֹב וְאֶת־עֵשָׂו שָׂנֵאתִי" (מלאכי א:ב-ג). וכדברי המלאך:
> "וַיֹּאמֶר לֹא יַעֲקֹב יֵאָמֵר עוֹד שִׁמְךָ כִּי אִם־יִשְׂרָאֵל כִּי־שָׂרִיתָ
> עִם־אֱלֹהִים וְעִם־אֲנָשִׁים וַתּוּכָל" (בר' לב:כט). יש מאבק מתמיד בין
> ישראל לאומות העולם במישור הרוחני והאידיאולוגי ("עם אלוקים") ובמישור
> המדיני ("ועם אנשים"), אבל יהיה סיום חיובי למאבק: "וַתּוּכָל".
>
> חז"ל אמרו: "אין קורין אבות אלא לשלושה".<sup>[5]</sup> כלומר, אין זה
> נכון לומר כי אברהם הוא האב רק שלנו, שהרי הוא גם אביו של ישמעאל, וכמו
> כן יצחק היה אביו של עשו. רק יעקב הוא זה שנקרא שמו ישראל, שממנו יצאו כל
> שבטי ישראל, אבל האבות בתור שורשים לאומה הישראלית הם יחידה אחת.  אברהם
> מבטא את האלמנט האוניברסלי; הוא "אַב הֲמוֹן גּוֹיִם" (בר' יז:ד) ומטרתו
> לקרב את העולם כולו לאמונה בא-ל אחד.<sup>[6]</sup> בנין האומה הישראלית
> מתחיל מיעקב, כדברי חז"ל על הפסוק "אֶל־בֵּית אֱלֹהֵי יַעֲקֹב" (יש' ב:ג):
> "לא כאברהם שכתוב בו הר, ולא כיצחק שכתוב בו שדה, אלא כיעקב שקראו
> בית".<sup>[7]</sup> הר פתוח לכולם אבל בית מיוחד למשפחה הדרה בו.
>
> אברהם בהיותו "אב המון גוים" הוא השורש האמוני של כל האומות: "ויקרא שם
> בשם ה' אל עולם" (בר' כא:לג), והוא גם שורש שלנו. אבל הבנין הפרטיקולרי
> של האומה מתחיל באופן מעשי ביעקב, אם כי נרמז כבר ביצחק: "כִּי בְיִצְחָק
> יִקָּרֵא לְךָ זָרַע" (בר' כא:יב). יש כאן חמש מדרגות בבניין האומה: אברהם
> – האלמנט האוניברסאלי, יצחק – תחילת בנין האומה, יעקב – בונה האומה
> בפועל, יוסף – המאבק לאורך הגלות, ויהודה – המלכות והתיקון הסופי. יצחק
> הוא הנקודה הקודמת לראשית הופעת האומה. יעקב (ישראל) הוא עיקר הבית,
> ואילו יוסף הוא זה שנאבק על מקומו של ישראל מול האומות. על כך יש רמז
> יפה. שם הוי"ה, שהוא השם המפורש, מספרו בגימטריה 26. יצחק = 208 = 26 X
> 8. יעקב = 182 = 26 X 7 ואילו יוסף = 156 = 26 X 6. יש כאן שלוש הופעות שונות של שם השם. הראשון הוא יצחק. ידוע מכתבי המהר"ל מפראג שמספר שבע
> בתנ"ך מסמל את הטבע, ומספר שמונה מסמל דבר שהוא מעל לטבע (כמו ברית מילה
> שמצוותה ביום השמיני שהוא שינוי בטבע. היא מסמלת את הברית עם הא-ל וגם את
> כל יתר 612 מצוות אשר יחד עמה בגימטריה -ברי"ת). יצחק היה הראשון שנימול
> ביום שמיני. לאחר העקידה הוא נשאר "עולה תמימה", מנותק מהעולם הזה, ועל
> כן היה צורך בעבד אברהם שיביא לו את אשתו. יצחק כמעט ואינו מדבר בספר
> בראשית. הוא כמעט ואינו יוזם דבר חדש; הוא חופר את אותן הבארות שחפר
> אברהם אביו וסתמום פלישתים, וקורא לאשתו בעת צרה "אחותו", כפי שעשה אביו.
> יעקב, המסומל במספר שבע, מבטא את ההופעה של שם ה' בטבע הכולל גם ימי חול
> וגם שבתות. על כן הוא נאבק עם לבן אבל יחד עם זאת הוא זוכה לברכות ארציות
> ושמימיות יחדיו, ככתוב: "הַקֹּל קוֹל יַעֲקֹב וְהַיָּדַיִם יְדֵי עֵשָׂו"
> (בר' כז:כב).
>
> כל ענייני יעקב רומזים למספר שבע שהוא שלמות הטבע: הוא קיבל את כל שבע
> הברכות מאביו (רש"י, 7X1); על-פי חז"ל הוא למד בבית המדרש של שם ועבר
> במשך ארבע עשרה שנה (7X2). הוא עבד שבע שנים בעד רחל (בר' כח:יח), וכאשר
> ניתנה לו לאה במקומה, הוא מילא את שבע ימי המשתה (בר' כט:כז) ועבד שבע
> שנים נוספות בעד רחל (בר' כט:ל). היו לו אמנם שנים עשר בנים ובת, אבל הבן
> השביעי שנולד לו היה גד (בר' ל:יא, וגד = 7). בסך הכול הוא עבד עשרים
> ואחת שנים בבית לבן (7X3) והוא ירד למצרים עם שבעים נפש (7X10). יש גם
> גילאים משמעותיים בחייו הקשורים למספר שבע. לפי רש"י, בגיל ששים ושלוש
> הוא קיבל את הברכות מאביו (7X9), בגיל תשעים ואחת הוא הוליד את יוסף
> (7X13) ובגיל מאה ארבעים ושבע (7X21) הוא נפטר (בר' מז:כח). המצריים
> התאבלו עליו 70 יום (בר' נ:ג).<sup>[8]</sup> בעל הטורים מפרש את הפסוק
> "ויחי יעקב" ש "ויחי" = 34. בהיותו בגיל 130 אמר יעקב לפרעה שחייו היו
> "מעט ורעים", אבל 17 השנים האחרונות היו טובות. וגם 17 שנים הראשונות של
> יוסף לפני מכירתו היו שנים טובות. בסך הכול 34 שנים היו טובות וכולן
> קשורות לימי יוסף (4+3=7).
>
> יוסף, ששמו שווה לשם הוי"ה שש פעמים כמו ששת ימי החול, מסמל את המאבק עם
> כוחות החולין. הוא שטנו של עשו והוא הנלחם לכל אורך הגלות על הישרדותם של
> ישראל בגולה. יוסף בגימטריה – "ציון" (156), כי עניינו להביא את העם
> לציון "וְהַעֲלִתֶם אֶת־עַצְמֹתַי מִזֶּה" (בר' נ:כה), וכמו כל בניה של
> רחל, עניינו "ראשית": ראשית המלוכה (שאול מבנימין מבניה של רחל), ראשית
> הקדושה (משכן שילה שהיה בחלקו של יוסף), וראשית הגאולה (משיח בן יוסף
> הנלחם מלחמות ישראל על הארץ ויקבץ נידחי ישראל).<sup>[9]</sup> אז יושלם
> תפקידו, וכשיושלם תפקידו של יוסף יגיע זמן תפקידו של יהודה שממנו המלכות
> והתיקון הסופי של עם ישראל. על כן, אף שספר בראשית מסתיים בנקודה זו,
> חז"ל הוסיפו לנו את ההפטרה על פטירתו של דוד שהוא המשיח האחרון.

Basically, the six refer to the worldliness of Yosef's life. This explains IMHO why the five books of Moshe were given at Sinai (130=5*26).

I believe this number represents a Godly spark that's reincarnated. Just as Pinchas and Eliyahu equal 26*10 (260), so too [Abaya and Rava equal 26*9  (234)](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1713761/jewish/Abaye-amp-Souls-of-Converts-345a.htm):

> "Abaya and Rava equal 234 in gematria. It is the same gematria as
> A”B/S”G/M”H/B”N - the primary permutations of YHVH, from which all
> yichudim [Divine name unifications] come. As seen from this whole
> compilation, the Cain/Ben Azzai/Abaya/R.Chaim Vital etc. root is the
> main one for yichudim - upon which the redemption depends."

This spark eventually will be reincarnated in Tziyon with Moshiach ben Yosef as we find in [Kol HaTor 2:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_HaTor.2?ven=Kol_HaTor&lang=en) (cit. Gen. 39:5):

> “the blessing of God ... in the house and in the field” -- This verse
> was said regarding Yosef. This blessing is included in the secret of
> the six names of God which, together, in gematria equal 156 (26x6).
> “Yosef” equals 156, and so does “Zion.”

---

- הרב ד"ר רפאל שוח"ט מרצה בבית הספר ללימודי יסוד ביהדות, אוניברסיטת בר-אילן.

<sup>[1](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1713761/jewish/Abaye-amp-Souls-of-Converts-345a.htm)</sup> - **תולדות יצחק**, ניו יורק תשס"ג, עמ' רכג.

<sup>[2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_HaTor.2?ven=Kol_HaTor&lang=en)</sup> - **קול אליהו** השלם, ירושלים תשל"ה, פרשת מקץ, עמ' יז.

<sup>[3]</sup> - **הגדה של פסח**. וראה מדרש **ספרי** על פרשת כי תבוא סימן שא, ד"ה "ואמרת".

<sup>[4]</sup> - **בראשית רבא** עח, יד.

<sup>[5]</sup> - ברכות טז ע"ב.

<sup>[6]</sup> - כדברי רש"י לבר' יב:ה: "אברהם מגייר את האנשים ושרי מגיירת הנשים".

<sup>[7]</sup> - פסחים פח ע"א.

<sup>[8]</sup> - אני מודה למר דניאל גולדשטיין על הערותיו בעניין זה.

<sup>[9]</sup> - ראו הראי"ה קוק, **שמעות ראיה**, ירושלים תשל"ג , פ' וישב, עמ' פג-פד.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read this from [Shemot Ba’aretz](http://cdn.yeshshem.com/docs/ShemotBaaretzFromAvrahamSutton.pdf)?

I don't know the author of this [website](https://godssecret.wordpress.com/category/gematria/), but he notes a bunch of Gematria:

> 208=8x 26 = יצחק
>
> 182= 7x 26= יעקב
>
> 130 = 5 x 26 = סיני
>
> 676 =26 x 26 = קהל ישראל
>
> 1820 = 70 x 26 = times יהו“ה appears in the Torah
>
> There are 26 generations from Adam to Moshe
>
> The 10 commandments occupy 26 lines in the Torah
>
> There is exactly 182 letters in the “Brachah Avot” of the Amidah = 7x
> 26
>
> week day “Amida” invokes יהו“ה 26

Moshe Friedman observes:

> The gematria of the names Eliyahu plus Pinchus is 52 + 208 = 260,
> which is 10 x 26, another level of completeness of the Divine Name
> Hashem gematria 26.

I'm guessing this is based on the Arizal.

I found this on a random website:

> « Si on… » se dit « Im anakhnou… »en hébreu. אם אנחנו Guematria = 156
> = guematria de « Tsion » (« Sion ») ציון
> = YHVH (26) x 6 יהוה 26 est la guematria du nom de Dieu YHVH. Le nombre 6 est lié à la sefira Yessod, « Sion »

This blogger then brings a bunch of random stuff and somehow ties it into the 26-dimensions of string theory:

> 26 est le seul nombre situé entre un carré (25) et un cube (27)
>
> 26 x 26 = 676 676 est le 26ème [nombre carré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carr%C3%A9_parfait)

From my own observations, when you agglomerate a bunch of these "numerical anomolies," you start to notice that they're no so random after all. I understand that one can simply comb through the data and make the theory fit (painting the target around the arrow), so I can only make a broad assertion that 26 is the seal or sigil of Hashem.

Comment: There are no prescribed number of lines for the 10 commandments in the Torah. There are plenty of versions of the first bracha of the Amidah with a different number of letters. There are plenty of versions of the Amidah with a different number of shemot. What does Eliyahu + Pinchas mean? Why do you think this is from the Arizal? What does אם אנחנו have to do with the name of God? What does 25 being square and 27 being cube have to do with string theory?

Comment: Rav Meir Goldwicht
Ki Lekach Tov Natati Lechem
Summarized and trans by Ariel Lewis (5775) & Lior Cohen (Hakotel 5777)
The days between Pesach and Shavuot are days of preparation for receiving the Torah. It is 
interesting that in Parshat Yitro, the Torah depicts the giving of the Torah in twenty-six verses 
and the ten commandments in thirteen verses. Twice the amount of time is spent regarding the 
preparations, highlighting the utmost significance of the preparation.

Comment: What nusach are you referring to? I would imagine this is nusach Arizal, but I'll investigate later.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are new to Judaism, so this may be hard to explain. Eliyahu is a gilgul or a reincarnation of Pinchas: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1577372/jewish/From-Pinchas-to-Elijah-322.htm

Comment: I mentioned the Arizal because I'm not sure if the Zohar talks about the gilgulim of Pinchas off the top of my head.

Comment: These are all things that should be clarified in the answer.

Comment: In the first bracha of the Amidah, the Italian rite as practiced in Jerusalem has two "extra" words, minhag P'ras has several "extra" words, and the Rokeach seems to be "missing" a letter (קונה), and the Baladi rite is "missing" למען שמו באהבה and switches in רחמן for עוזר, to name a few — not to mention the dozens of genizah texts that are more radically different.